# Python Os.walk Filter Filenames (What extensions not to include and skip dirs)

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
filetypes = ("*.jpg","*.txt","*.csv")
filelist = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("c:\\"):
 for ft in filetypes:
  for f in fnmatch.filter(filenames, ft):
   filelist.append(os.path.join(root, f))
```

I have this code which will add to my list only files with the extensions I provide,

1) I want to do the opposite add all file extensions `"*.*"` and filter some of them I don't need for example `"*.dat","*.dll","*.log","*.exe"`

2) Also I do not need files from `c:\\windows c:\\program files c:\\else` can I filter it too?

3) I need it to be fast found this example code from other answer it seems to be faster but what is main speed issue in this type of function os.walk? If so there is scandir github project 7-20 times faster os.walk improved function, or if it's the filtering of file matches by extensions i want to filter 20+ extensions any suggestions?

```
    import os
    extns = ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.tif', '.tiff')
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, fns in os.walk("C:\\"):
        matches.extend(os.path.join(root, fn) for fn in fns if fn.lower().endswith(extns))
```

Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you are asking. Do you have specific questions?

Comment: Any way you do it is going to be slow.  The only two things I can think of are: 1) use the GitHub scandir module (I've not used it, I can only assume the results are legit); 2) use pre-compiled regular expressions to match (you'll need one for extensions, and one for dirs).  You'll want to test this, as when you use a regex it may induce a slow-down that negates the affects of scandir.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import os
import sys
import re
import fnmatch

def findit(root, exclude_files=[], exclude_dirs=[]):
    exclude_files = (fnmatch.translate(i) for i in exclude_files)
    exclude_files = '('+')|('.join(exclude_files)+')'
    exclude_files = re.compile(exclude_files)
    exclude_dirs = (os.path.normpath(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
    exclude_dirs = (os.path.normcase(i) for i in exclude_dirs)
    exclude_dirs = set(exclude_dirs)
    return (os.path.join(r,f)
           for r,_,f in os.walk(root)
           if os.path.normpath(os.path.normcase(r)) not in exclude_dirs
           for f in f
           if not exclude_files.match(os.path.normcase(f)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   # If you need the entire list in memory at once
   filelist = list(findit('c:/',
                exclude_files = ['*.dll', '*.dat', '*.log', '*.exe'],
                exclude_dirs = ['c:/windows', 'c:/program files', 'c:/else'],
               ))

   # Or this, if you need the items one at a time (saves memory):
   for filename in findit('c:/',
                exclude_files = ['*.dll', '*.dat', '*.log', '*.exe'],
                exclude_dirs = ['c:/windows', 'c:/program files', 'c:/else'],
               ):
       print filename # or stat() or open() the file, or whatever.
```

Comment: I have tried your code it doesn't seems to exclude_dirs (List exmaple) well the file names count stays the same

Comment: @Rob Thank you Rob awesome code, exactly what I wanted the folders exclude also seems not to work for me (or it's not working in a way to exclude the files if those dirs are excluded?) when I tried local testig "remove.dirname" it will ignore the filenames also

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to write a more flexible os.walk to filter dirs and files with a regex, but using pathlib2 functions.
Here it is.

```
import regex
from pathlib2 import Path

def _recursedir_(self, depth=-1, exclude=None, invert=False):
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    depth : int, optional
        depth to stop at, if less than 0 then don't stop. The default is -1.
    exclude : compiled regex expression, or dict of regex expressions, keys 'dir', 'file', optional
        regex to match current dir/file name against. The default is None.
    invert : bool or dict of bools, keys 'dir', 'file', optional
        invert the sense of the filter, default is to skip filter matches. The default is False.

    Yields
    ------
    Path
        Current dir path.
    List of dirs
        SubDirs in current path.
    List of files
        Files in current path.

    '''
    if type(exclude) is dict:
        dfilt = exclude['dir']
        ffilt = exclude['file']
    else:
        dfilt = exclude
        ffilt = None  # means show all files in current path
    if type(invert) is dict:
        dsens = invert['dir']
        fsens = invert['file']
    else:
        dsens = invert
        fsens = False  # means skip files that match

    if dfilt is None:
        dfun = lambda x : True
    elif dsens is False:
        dfun = lambda x : not dfilt.match(x.name)  # filter match EXCLUDES
    else:
        dfun = lambda x : dfilt.match(x.name)      # filter match INCLUDES
    if ffilt is None:
        ffun = lambda x: True
    elif fsens is False:
        ffun = lambda x : not ffilt.match(x.name)  # filter match EXCLUDES
    else:
        ffun = lambda x : ffilt.match(x.name)      # filter match INCLUDES
    

    d = self.resolve()
    dd = [ x for x in d.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
    f  = [ x for x in d.iterdir() if x.is_file()]

    dd[:] = [ x for x in filter(dfun, dd )]
    f[:] = [ x for x in filter(ffun, f)]

    yield (d, dd, f)
    if depth > 0 or depth < 0:
        for xd in dd:
            yield from _recursedir_( d / xd,  depth=depth-1, exclude=exclude, invert=invert)

Path.recursedir = _recursedir_
```

So the call to this method is, given a Path variable e.g.

```
for dir, dlist, flist in Path.home().recursedir(depth = 3, exclude=re.compile(r'\d+'), invert = True ):
    print(f"{d} : {dlist} : {flist}")
```

This will (should !) limit the depth to 3, and exclude all DIRS that begin with digits.

So for multiple file extension matching, one would use,

```
exclude = { 'dir':None, 'file':re.compile(r'.*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|txt)')}
```